# Resetting and Reconfiguring AWS EB After Large Backend Changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, django, elastic-beanstalk

I had a Python 2.7 Django project I was running as an Elastic Beanstalk Application, which also utilized a S3 bucket for numerous resources. I ran into compatibility issues that necessitated switching to Python 3.6. I have already properly reconfigured my virtual environment to the right version, and ran local tests and have completed the conversion.

However, I have been completely unsuccessful when it comes to redeploying this application either on the previous EB instance or a new instance. I am unable to update the previous elastic beanstalk environment from Python 2.7 to 3.6 (or any version other than 2.7). When I created a new EB configured for using Python 3.6, the deployed web server failed to start, where I used the AWS console GUI or the EB CLI. Accessing this url states: "Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server." Attempting to use the EB CLI to change the server version of my initial server did not seem to work, and the AWS console still shows that server as being registered as a Python 2.7 server.

In short my question falls into 2 main approaches:

**1. How can I update my 2.7 Elastic Beanstalk Webserver to a 3.6 version for redeploying my application?**

If not, then

**2. What is the proper procedure for me to purge all relevant user and server configurations, deployment instructions, and other files that might interfere with creating a new Python 3.6 application, so that I can  create a new Elastic Beanstalk instance and deploy the application?**

For part 2, are there any reconfiguration for my S3 bucket I need to also include or as long as I have my IAM user info all configurations are handled?

Comment: I am in the same boat and am working through this.    I've updated the yum packages, the `eb config`, and tried to interrupt the deployment to use python 3.6, all to no avail.   I am considering switching directly to an ec2 instance and not use eb